# How to stack selected columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression

I am not quite sure if this is the right place to post this question.

I have to do a logistic regression using R. Now the programming part should not be an issue as there is enough tutorials and similar questions on these forums already.

My question is more about how to get data into usable form this model.

To specify: The survey is about a tax on a specific consumer good. Specifically on the change in the consumers purchasing behaviour. There were two categories that people were randomly selected for. One with tax and the other without. Additionaly, two different situations were people were asked about their preferences. So to sum up, Group A were taxed on the good in both situations, Group B was not taxed in either situation.

The results are now in a CSV file. The problem now is, however, all those subgroups got their own respective column. This means that this can't be evaluated well as they should all be merged into one to then create a logistic regression with a 1 if a person has chosen the taxed good and 0 if they did not. This should then be evaluated to see if a tax on said good would reduce the amount bought by x percent, if the tax even has an impact on purchasing behaviour. (This may not apply to this question but is more aimed towards clarification. Logistic regression will not tell me the before mentioned point)

My question now is, is there even a way to make this work with the design chosen? Is it possible to merge all the data into usable form without losing / distorting any data?

I am not sure if this question is stated clearly enough. Let me know if I should clarify more details for this question to be properly answered.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:

The columns in the CSV file now each have a number in them corresponding to the choice they made in the survey. But since there were different groups they all got their respective column. For a logistic regression they have to be all in the same column (I believe). Can I just stack them using the links posted in the comments and go from there?

Also. Does it not distort any data when just stacking columns? I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this but I think it's worth a try.

Comment: We have no idea on what columns there are exactly in your csv. It seems that you might want to pivot the columns using [pivot_longer](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html)

Comment: Your actual question, if I understood correctly, boils down to: "How can I stack selected columns of a dataframe?". You may find some of the existing answers helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+stack+columns

Comment: @danlooo I edited the post to hopefully make it clearer. But I will check out pivot longer. Thank you

Comment: @I_O Thanks for the link. I guess that is the question yes. I find it difficult to describe it clearly but I will check out those answers and see if they help.

Comment: Personally, I prefer `pivot_longer()` of package {tidyr} because it plays along well with the rest of the tidyverse ( https://www.tidyverse.org/ ), but you also have, e.g., `stack` of package {utils}.

Comment: What is the response variable? Please post at least part of your dataset, for instance using `myData <- read.csv(...); dput(head(myData, 20))`.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try, is splitting the csv, in two seperate datasets (one for each group) and use rbind to combine them:

```
# note: the column names needs to be identical in order for them to stack
df_final <- rbind(df1, df2)
```